# SQL query to get the precision value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need a sql query that gets the precision value for certain columns.. I am mainly concerned with a decimal type column and I need the precision value for the same.

I realise that it is possible to do so in certain versions and vendors of database servers. It  would be nice if you could list down for a few of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle:

```
SELECT DATA_LENGTH, DATA_PRECISION
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = :TableName
AND COLUMN_NAME = :ColumnName
```

Firebird (+ Interbase) :

```
SELECT
       rdb$field_scale,
       rdb$field_precision
FROM   rdb$relations r
       JOIN rdb$relation_fields rf
         ON rf.rdb$relation_name = r.rdb$relation_name
       JOIN rdb$fields fld
         ON rf.rdb$field_source = fld.rdb$field_name
WHERE  r.rdb$relation_name = :TableName
       AND rf.rdb$field_name = :ColumnName
```

MySql (Not Tested !) :

```
SELECT
  NUMERIC_PRECISION,  NUMERIC_SCALE
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  TABLE_NAME  = :TableName AND
  COLUMN_NAME = :ColumnName
```

Answer (score 10):

for sql server:

```
select precision from sys.columns where name='<column_name>'
```

for oracle:

```
select data_precision from all_tab_columns  where column_name = '<columnName>'
```

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server you can also use `NUMERIC_PRECISION` in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

I assume this may well be portable.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, it's:

```
select object_name(object_id), name, precision from sys.columns
```

Answer (score 0):

For FireBird and InterBase

```
SELECT 
  RDB$FIELD_PRECISION, RDB$FIELD_SCALE
FROM RDB$FIELDS
WHERE RDB$FIELD_NAME = columnsDomainName
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
SELECT numeric_precision,
       numeric_scale
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name';
```