# SQL query to print values with precision > 4

Tags: mysql, sql-server, precision

I want to write a SQL query which will display all the values in a column which have precision > 4 i.e. exactly four digits after the decimal point.
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318683/sql-query-to-get-the-precision-value-of-a-column) and have come up with a query for sql server. 
I do not know if this is correct.
Also I want to know how to do the same in MySQL.

```
select colname from tablename where (select precision from sys.columns 
where name='<colname>') > 4;
```

Comment: `mysql <> sql-server`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I know that but I what I have attempted is the sql-server query and I also want to know how to do the same thing if you are using MySQL.